# Getting 401/404 errors with Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services API

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-cognitive-services

I followed the directions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/computervision/3.1/describeimage/describeimage but each time I fill in my endpoint, as https://[resource_name].cognitiveservices.azure.com or https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsot.com, I get a 404 or 401 error, respectively. I've checked to make sure the image url I specify works and loads fine withOUT a 404. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both hosts below to send request:

```
https://<your service name>.cognitiveservices.azure.com
https://<your service loaction>.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
```

You can find all of then on Azure Portal=>Cognitive services=>your service =>Keys and Endpoint:

[image]

You should involve key as request header:`Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` to avoid 401 error just as below:

[image]
[image]

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: thank you! it worked after I started using key2 and the resource-name.cognitiveservices.azure.com endpoint. Not sure why key1 still returned a 401, but oh well.